# Unable to delete network bridges on Fedora 33 & Docker

Tags: fedora, docker, bridge, nmcli

I am using Docker 20.10.7 on Fedora 33:

```
$ uname -r
5.12.8-200.fc33.x86_64
$ docker -v
Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350
```

When trying to create a new docker network, I get the following error:

```
$ docker network create --subnet 172.18.128.0/17 si
Error response from daemon: cannot create network 87c3cae81d6e379b4fec55a671fc26e547debc218d16b9e762435b7aa6f9ca28 (br-87c3cae81d6e): conflicts with network 8247c1fe85afa51c174529086ad8bc58069e8aac336cc99239b2cce21311ecb9 (br-8247c1fe85af): networks have overlapping IPv4
```

Although no docker networks apart from the defaults seem to exist:

```
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME      DRIVER    SCOPE
93e55f691850   bridge    bridge    local
57062f01a833   host      host      local
3f81078d2755   none      null      local
```

It seems that some network bridges are present. These may be remnants of docker networks which have since been deleted:

```
$ brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br-0ccb5edb60fa     8000.02425e65824c   no      
br-0ebff3222c7d     8000.0242ad165003   no      
br-13b92f8a402d     8000.0242fd54405d   no      
br-3fe8819f1dab     8000.0242df196682   no      
br-62855eeb66b1     8000.024279b970d4   no      
br-64f88c232b42     8000.024294a697d3   no      
br-6cb52985982b     8000.0242fa683006   no      
br-7b91629f9dc5     8000.02429075dacd   no      
br-8247c1fe85af     8000.0242da4e1ba9   no      
br-9e6e08fae543     8000.0242a0c94c05   no      
br-b04024820e6b     8000.024251673cfb   no      
br-bb03dc88def2     8000.0242d550a519   no      
br-c3bfd0e7bfac     8000.02420fc70d06   no      
br-f446efca8607     8000.02423c5f7dff   no      
br-fc4085566463     8000.0242c5a5a9ed   no      
docker0     8000.0242090fcff7   no
```

So my idea was to delete these bridges, thinking that creating the new docker network should work after that:

```
$ sudo ip link del br-0ccb5edb60fa # do this for all bridges
$ brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
docker0     8000.0242090fcff7   no
```

But alas, the error remains:

```
$ docker network create --subnet 172.18.128.0/17 si
Error response from daemon: cannot create network 60b9a9c6f1b032cf54ac799e5b8f2a96b1d55a05492e5357ffb6b002f10a27de (br-60b9a9c6f1b0): conflicts with network fc4085566463d57a641dbb3f5bba4888dbdf3908868f30d4e0c46edf19c001e4 (br-fc4085566463): networks have overlapping IPv4
```

I thought restarting the docker service might solve the problem

```
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

But after restarting the docker service, the bridges reappear!

```
$ brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br-0ccb5edb60fa     8000.0242ba61c513   no      
br-0ebff3222c7d     8000.0242ae82887a   no      
br-13b92f8a402d     8000.02421fa70d86   no      
br-3fe8819f1dab     8000.0242a7c0d3cd   no      
br-62855eeb66b1     8000.02423b35c43d   no      
br-64f88c232b42     8000.0242e3235138   no      
br-6cb52985982b     8000.024264333192   no      
br-7b91629f9dc5     8000.02420c574876   no      
br-8247c1fe85af     8000.02423b3845ee   no      
br-9e6e08fae543     8000.024285a4da86   no      
br-b04024820e6b     8000.02425a16a19f   no      
br-bb03dc88def2     8000.02422c2da231   no      
br-c3bfd0e7bfac     8000.024250df5e93   no      
br-f446efca8607     8000.024234091377   no      
br-fc4085566463     8000.0242eda476ce   no      
docker0     8000.0242090fcff7   no
```

Other things I have tried, but which did not help:

```
$ docker network prune -f
$ docker system prune -f
# tried the following commands for all existing bridges
$ nmcli connection delete br-0ccb5edb60fa
$ sudo brctl delbr br-0ccb5edb60fa
$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=docker --remove-interface=br-0ccb5edb60fa --permanent
Warning: NOT_ENABLED: br-0ccb5edb60fa
success
```

What may be preventing me from reliably deleting network bridges?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why docker kept recreating brigdes. They seem to be stored in `/var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db`, a binary file (BoltDB), which explains why I didn't catch it with a `grep`.

Deleting the file and restarting docker solved my problem.
The following commands (executed in `zsh`, other shells may be different) delete all bridges, the aforementioned file and restart the docker service.
After that, I am able to create the docker network without errors.

```
while read; do
  if [ ! -z "$REPLY" ]; then
    sudo ip link del $REPLY
  fi
done <<<"$(brctl show | grep '^br-' | awk '{print $1}')"
sudo rm /var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db
sudo systemctl restart docker
```